# Remove (XX.. rows affected) from SQLCMD output to file

Tags: sqlcmd

Using **SQLCMD** with -o to file.

How to get rid of the (XX... rows affected) message at the end for a clean output?

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014129/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-x-rows-affected-in-sqlcmd-from-the-command-line) think link

Comment: Perfect, thanks! -Q "set nocount on;SELECT..." did the job